# Parallax scrolling with multiple backgrounds and mobile suitable

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, parallax, gyroscope

I've been researching a variety of jQuery plugins that provide the following features at once:

1. Background scrolling parallax effect.
2. Multiple backgrounds (layers).
3. Responsive.
4. Gyrospopic/motion detection.

Thus far, I can only find plugins with *some* of these features.

- [Wagerfield Parallax.JS](http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/): Everything but background scrolling. Also undesirably detects cursor beyond container which isn't great for multiple parallax elements.
- [Nikebetterworld Parallax Effect](http://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/recreate-nikebetterworld-parallax/): Everything but responsive (breaks on mobile) and gyroscopic/motion detection.
- [jParallax](http://stephband.info/jparallax/): Everything but gyroscopic/motion detection or any mobile support whatsoever for that matter.

## Plan B

If I have to accept that parallax background scrolling AND gyroscopic/motion detection does not yet exist, I'm willing to settle for a solid recommendation on a plugin that offers parallax background scrolling AND works on mobile devices.

Comment: Parallax.js by pixelcog.js is worth mentioning for "Plan B" reference in my question. It produces a static background on mobiles rather than breaking. Additionally, here's an educational article I found on the cons of parallax: http://www.designyourway.net/drb/how-the-web-design-trend-of-parallax-scrolling-has-faded/